# set 100% width to highchart chart in jquery dialog window

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highchart in a div container, inside a dialog make with JQuery.

The problem is the width of the chart, is less than 100%, but when I resize the windows (of the browser, not dialog window), the chart resize to 100% of his container.

Ideas???

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want chart not to be resized, so check the link http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=21421 or http://jsfiddle.net/YH9vs/1/  Here width and height is set  to defined values, so chart remains same even after resizing browser window.

Comment: You can try to call setSize function in chart, other way is using jquery.width() and place in chart confiuration, but without any live example we cannot predict which solution will be fine